# Socket hang up error on GET request in nest js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, node-modules

I have an function in my Nest js app that return an object with data, but when i try to map this data I get this error

"Error: socket hang up".

```
    private getItems(page = '1', pageSize = 10): Observable<{ data: []; progress: number }> {
        return this.http
            .get('https://example.com/search/items?proceduresTypes=%5B%22directAward%22%5D', {
                params: { pageSize, page, cdb: 'items' }
            })
            .pipe(
                map(({ data }) => {
                    if (data.code !== 200) {
                        this.logger.error(data);
                        throw new Error(data);
                    }
                    return {
                        data: data.data.map((value) => plainToClass(Tender0Dto, value)),
                        progress: (+page / +data._meta.pageCount) * 100,
                    };
                }),
            );
    }
```

I try to make this request in postman and they return me object with data and status 200 but when I try to do in nest js I get this error.

Comment: Try adding a `catchError` to the `pipe` like this `catchError(val => of(`I caught: ${val}`))` and see if the server responds with some other message. You may be missing some additional headers.

Comment: Most interesting is that some time has worked and now i have this problem, and code as it was and remained.